# Database-Per-Tenant Azure - Newbie

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I have been asked to create an Entity Framework ASP.NET MVC web site that runs in Azure. Each customer will have their data stored in a dedicated copy of the database, but, and here's the rub, their databases must reside in their own country/area's Azure data center. The app would know where to connect, we'd store the customer's "Azure location connection string" in a common database so our web site would know where to connect.

The big question is: I assume this is possible, but don't know where to start. I am assuming when a client first signs up to the service that we can execute a kind of database creation script and have that run in Azure data centers of our choosing. Eg Germany, Brazil and Canada would be clients' countries.

Comment: I don't think this is so complicated,but there is one issue i could see..say for example,if you are US, you can't create database in some regions of Germany due to some laws.My subscription got expired, so i couldn't test and remeber now,you may also need to check on whether a server created in one region  can host database of another region..?

Comment: I also recommend you to use elastic pools,since you may use multiple databases..this can help you lower costs as well..Also there will be new sql azure managed instance(just like onpremises server ,but no maintenance needed) coming  by the end of year,check it out and see if it helps

Comment: When the customer wants to sign up, you can either detect their IP address and based on that you can select which Azure area to select, or you can have a drop downlist where the client select. after that i advise to have a code first db to generate the db instead of using sql script, since it would be much more manageable and up-gradable in the future. to be more specific which part to you need help with? the creation of the db or location detection?